# Getting system locale using java.locale.providers

Tags: java, locale, java-8

I want to get my system locale using Java 8's java.locale.providers property. My system locale is UK but this code returns US every time. What am I doing wrong?

```
String localeProvidersList = System.getProperty("java.locale.providers",  "HOST");      
System.out.println(Locale.getDefault().getCountry());
```

Comment: That seems like a property you need to set.

Comment: System properties `user.country, user.language, user.variant`; `Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT)`

Comment: Why do you think that calling **getProperty** has any significance?

Answer (score 1):

Reading [the documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/locale-140624.html#using), the following seems relevant:

> Retrieve the default locale using the following method:
>
> `public static Locale getDefault()`
>
> The default locale of your application is determined in three ways. First,
>   unless you have explicitly changed the default, the `getDefault()` method 
>   returns the locale that was initially determined by the Java Virtual Machine 
>   (JVM) when it first loaded. That is, the JVM determines the default locale 
>   from the host environment. The host environment's locale is determined by the 
>   host operating system and the user preferences established on that system.
>
> Second, on some Java runtime implementations, the application user can 
>   override the host's default locale by providing this information on the 
>   command line by setting the `user.language`, `user.country`, and 
>   `user.variant` system properties.
>
> ⋮
>
> Third, your application can call the `setDefault(Locale aLocale)` method. The 
>   `setDefault(Locale aLocale)` method lets your application set a systemwide 
>   resource. After you set the default locale with this method, subsequent calls 
>   to `Locale.getDefault()` will return the newly set locale.

So assuming there are no calls to `Locale.setDefault()`, I'd rule out anything overriding the "hosts default locale" by using something like the following:

```
public class Default { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.language")); 
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.country")); 
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.variant")); 
    } 
}
```

And if that doesn't provide any suggestion as to why you're getting a US locale, I'd have to presume that somehow your computer doesn't have its locale set as you expect, or else it's failing to tell the JVM correctly.